# Take two cells, and compare which value is greater then use the highest value to calculate a percentage in a 3rd cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I have two cells with different numerical values. For example Y2 equals 15, and Z2 equals 10. Then I have a third cell that needs to take the highest value and multiple it by a percentage G2.

For G2, currently its just taking =sum(Y2*1.5), but I need to detect if Y2 is greater than Z2, and use the greater number in place of Y2. If Z2 is greater, it should be =sum(Z2*1.5). I know that you can use =Y2>=Z2 but I'm unsure how to mix that into the sum function.

I appreciate the guidance!

Comment: Try `=SUM(MAX(Y2,Z2),1.5)`

Comment: Calculating percentage `=MAX(Y2,Z2)*1.5`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked was having Y2, and Z2 with there values, creating a new column that checks if Y2 is greater than Z2 which will display true or false. Then in the G2 cell run a formula like this: =if(Z2=TRUE,X2*1.5,Y2*1.5)